# RShiny unable to load css file with external HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I am developing Shiny app, I created UI code with HTML, CSS and js and kept them in **www** sub-folder and app.R in main folder.

and my code in app in as follows

```
runApp(
shinyApp(
    ui = shinyUI(
        htmlTemplate("www/index.html")  
    ),  
    server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    })
))
```

When I am trying to run app code, it is appending CSS and JS.

Please help me out with to sort this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my `template.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    {{ headContent() }}
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- JavaScript code that uses D3 here -->

    {{ d3heatmap::d3heatmap(mtcars, scale="column", colors="Blues") }}
  </body>
</html>
```

and `app.R` file

```
shinyApp(
    ui = shinyUI(
        htmlTemplate("template.html")  
    ),  
    server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    })
)
```

with the `template.html` just inside the app folder where `app.R` is also located!

Hope it helps!